# What is the best practice to use content-security-policy with an Angular site?

Tags: angular, iis, websecurity

I'm currently trying to secure an Angular website with security headers in IIS.
So far most of the header work without any error, but I'm stuck with the content-security-policy header.

I ended up using values like 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' etc, from which i understand is not really ideal.

Is there a default stringent CSP header that can be used and relaxed until no more errors appear with an angular site or any suggestions on a best-practice on how use it with an angular site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following content security policy worked with my angular site:

```
connect-src 'self';
default-src 'self';
object-src 'none';
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
worker-src 'none';
font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:;
img-src 'self' data:;
```